# Rotation about an axis by matrix multiplication

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, rotations, quaternions

Suppose I have three axis of rotation vectors $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3}$ and angle of rotation as vectors $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$.

1. Take a vector $P$ then apply rotation around  $\vec{v_1}$  with rotation angle  $|\theta_1|$
2. From new orientation of $P$ apply rotation around  $\vec{v_2}$  with rotation angle  $|\theta_2|$
3. From new orientation of $P$ apply rotation around  $\vec{v_3}$  with rotation angle  $|\theta_3|$
4. Now you get final orientation of $P$

**Question**

1. Shall we get the same orientation of P if rotate  around  resultant of $\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},\vec{v_3}$ let us call V with an angle which is equal to the magnitude of the resultant of $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the resultant of $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$" ?

Comment: Means vector sum

Comment: But $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ are not vectors.

Comment: They are angles represented by vectors..As explained in the question magnitude of this is the angle in radian

Answer (score 1):

No (it is called “non-commutativity”).

First hint: rotate 90° around *z*, then 90° around *x*, then −90° around *z*.

When the first exercise was complete, try to rotate −90° around *z*, then 90° around *x*, then 90° around *z* ☺